# Get por id de un municipio luego de hacer un get por departamento

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Tengo un problema al querer realizar un get por id de un municipio y el id que necesito buscar es la elección de un get por departamento

Desde ya muchas gracias por el apoyo

```
<div class="col-md-3" >
  <label for="departamentoNac" class="autoSizingSelect">Departamento donde Nació</label>
  <select (change)="obtenerId($event)" name="departamentoNacSelect" class="form-select">
  <option value="{{departamentoNac.id}}"  *ngFor="let departamentoNac of departamentosNac" >{{departamentoNac.id}} - {{departamentoNac.nombre}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3" >
  <label for="municipioNac" class="autoSizingSelect">Municipio donde Nació</label>
  <select [value]="idMuni" name="municipioNacSelect" class="form-select">
  <option *ngFor="let municipio of municipios">{{municipio.id}} - {{municipio.nombre}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

```html
export class RegistroDatosGeneralesComponent implements OnInit {

  nacionalidades!: Nacionalidad[];
  idiomas!: Idioma[];
  departamentosNac!: DepartamentoNacimiento[];
  municipios!: Municipio[];
  idMuni!: any;  
  sub!: any;

  obtenerId( obtId: any ){
    this.idMuni = this.departamentosNac;
    console.log(this.idMuni);
    this.registrarUsuariosService.getMunicipioPorId(this.idMuni).subscribe
    (data => (this.municipios = data));
  }


  constructor(private registrarUsuariosService: RegistrarUsuariosService){ }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.registrarUsuariosService.getNacionalidades().subscribe
    (data => (this.nacionalidades = data) );

    this.registrarUsuariosService.getIdiomas().subscribe
    (data => (this.idiomas = data) );

    this.registrarUsuariosService.getDepartamentoNac().subscribe
    (data => (this.departamentosNac = data) );

    // let idMuni = this. departamentosNac.values.arguments.id;
  }

}
```

He tratado con la opción change pero estoy perdido cuando quiero obtener el departamento.id para hacer el getMunicipioId con el id del departamento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <div class="col-md-3" >
  <label for="departamentoNac" class="autoSizingSelect">Departamento donde Nació</label>
  <select (change)="obtenerId($event)" name="departamentoNacSelect" class="form-select">
  <option [value]="departamentoNac.id"  *ngFor="let departamentoNac of departamentosNac">{{departamentoNac.id}} - {{departamentoNac.nombre}}</option>
  </select>
</div>


obtenerId(event : Event) {
//this.selectedId = this.idMuni;
this.selectedId = (event.target as HTMLSelectElement).value;
console.log(this.selectedId)
this.registrarUsuariosService.getMunicipioPorId(this.selectedId).subscribe
(data => (this.municipios = data));
```

}

solucionado por sí alguien lo ocupa